# Generate text on a webpage which depends on dropdown box options

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I have created a dropdown box with 3 options on my website.

I want to change some text on the webpage, depending on the drop-down item selected. For example:

If dropdown option 1 is chosen, I would like some text on the page that says "*You have chosen option 1*".

I don't know any JavaScript and so I haven't tried anything apart from trying to search for a similar solution.

---

```
<select name="os0" style="background: #315d80; color: #fff; border-color: white; border: 0px;">
<option value="op1">Option 1</option>
<option value="op2">Option 2</option>
<option value="op3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you share your html atleast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full sultion with jQuery (I started typing it before you added the HTML to your question so the options are italian car brands).

https://jsfiddle.net/mL2c2xb6/

**HTML**:

```
<select id="carSelect">
    <option></option>
    <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
    <option value="Ferrari">Ferrari</option>
    <option value="Fiat">Fiat</option>
</select>

<p id="choiceDisplay">
    Selection Display
</p>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('select').change(function(){                // Listen to changes to <select> element
    const options = $("option");              // Get all the <option> elements.
    let selectedOption = "";                  // Var to store selected option value.
    options.each(function(index){             // Iterate  through option elements.
        let option = options[index];
        if($(option).prop("selected")) {      // Find the seletced one.
           selectedOption = $(option).val();  // Get the value and store it
        };
    });
    $("#choiceDisplay")
        .empty()
        .append(selectedOption);              // Display the result.
});
```

Comment: That's great - thank you so much! Is it a small modification if I want to my text to say something other than what is in the dropdown (but still dependent on the dropdown of course)? For example if the choice is "Audi", the text could be "Oh I used to have one of those".

Comment: `let displayString = ""; if(selecetedOption === "Audi") { displayString = "Oh I used to have one of those");`

Mess around with jsfiddle i linked you to it is a great playground to starting to figure out JS.

Answer (score 1):

```
var e = document.querySelector('[name="os0"]');
var strUser = "";
e.addEventListener("change", function(){
    strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  alert("You have chosen " + strUser);
});
```